# Can a normal SIM be modified to work as a nano-SIM?

Tags: sim, iphone, cellular-carriers

I just puchased an iPhone5 and want to use my current SIM from my existing phone. Is there a way to convert my existing SIM to nano-SIM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. You could cut it to the same dimensions, but the risk to damage the chip is high. Additionally the nano sim is slightly thinner, so it still wouldn't be a good fit.

I suggest you exchange your sim card with your operator. Note that there exist adapters to fit a nano sim in a larger form factor though.

Comment: I agree for most, the answer should be NO - just get a new SIM, but I don't want to spoil all DIY from trying it if they know the risks...

Answer (score 3):

The downsides of converting your [SIM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subscriber_identity_module) are:

- You no longer have a SIM to activate your old iOS phone (assuming it's an iPhone).
- If you mess up the cut, you still need to go get a new SIM (perhaps two)
- If your cut isn't precise, the SIM could wiggle loose later from the carrier since the nano-SIM carrier is designed for a thinner card and very precise dimensions.
- Your carrier might expect newer SIM in the devices and your service could be impacted (very low chance - but I've seen it happen with AT&T and older Cingular, other SIM's that eventually lose support if you don't get their newer numbered SIM cards).

The upside is you might skip a trip or a call to your carrier and if you are good at cutting, you can shave down an existing card if you really want that thrill of DIY.

[Engadget has a nice picture of the carriers](http://www.engadget.com/2012/09/13/nano-sim-adapter/) you could use to place a nano-SIM into a phone that expects a micro-SIM or SIM. Here are the micro-SIM and nano-SIM compared to some common coins for a reference to how small scale these are physically.

[image: Engadget photo of micro-SIM and nano-SIM]
<sup>Photo from [Engadget](http://www.engadget.com/2012/09/13/nano-sim-adapter/)</sup>
The real issue is if your contacts on your SIM (or micro-SIM) are placed in the correct places for the iPhone 5. Here is a picture showing that some micro-SIM have larger/different contact points than a nano-SIM.

[image: iPhone today photo of micro-SIM and nano-SIM]
<sup>Photo from [Today's iPhone](http://www.todaysiphone.com/2012/09/nano-sim-vs-micro-sim-size-comparison-just-how-small-is-it/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I've read a number of positive reports on DIY resizes. Apparently Apple allowed enough slack in the nano-SIM slot that the thicknesses is not an issue. It does require careful cutting and if you screw it up you'll need a new SIM. You can find templates and instructions on the Internet. I have not seen any punches yet for nano-SIM's.

As suggested, if possible, it's better to get a replacement nano-SIM if your carrier offers it.